# How to ignore or push back certain files when when auto-completing in wildmenu?

Tags: filetype, wildmenu

When opening a file with `:e`, `:vs` or `:sp`, I generally don't want to open binary files or files with certain extensions like `.class`.

Is there a way to ignore files with certain extensions or MIME type (or put them at the end of the completion options) in the wildmenu auto-complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'wildignore'` is a list of file patterns which be ignored for completing (among other things as well)

```
set wildignore+=*.class
```

`'suffixes'` is a list of file suffixes which will lower the priority of filename in completion

```
set suffixes+= class
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'wildignore'
:h 'suffixes'
```

Comment: how can I add multiple entries for them in 1 line?

Comment: Use `:set suffixes+=.class,.foo`